# How can I store these data into a list by splitting it as title, artist, duration and type from the file with python?

Tags: python

```
Con Altura  ROSALIA 162 party
One Thing Right Marshmello 182 workout
Te Robare Nicky Jam 202 workout
Happier Marshmello 214 workout
Call You Mine The Chainsmokers 218  relax
Cross Me (feat. Chance the Rapper & PnB Rock) Ed Sheeran 206 relax
```

for example Con Altura-> title, ROSALIA -> artist, 162 -> duration and party -> type.

I have a Song class consist of title, artist, duration and type but I don't know how to fetch data from the file according to attributes.

```
songList = [
    "title" : "Te Robare Nicky", "artist" : "Jam", "duration" : 202, "type" : "workout",
    "title" : "x", "artist" : "y", "duration" : z, "type" : "t",
    "title" : "a", "artist" : "b", "duration" : c, "type" : "d"
]
```

The above list is what I want to do actually. Basically after every song information I want to create a Song object store it into the list.

```
song = Song(title, artist, duration, type)
```

I am trying to fetch the data from the file as `songs = inp.readLines()`. Then I don't know what to do to split these according to attributes. And I have a Playlist class consist of 3 attributes and the songList. Therefore, at then end of inserting all songs into to I want to do

```
playlist = Playlist("g", "h", "t", songList)
```

How should solve this problem?

Comment: You'll need the text data to be comma separated or any other identifier separated to properly import and make it a list. Because, without it, we can't separate "One thing right" to be the name and Marshmello to be the artist directly. We could do it in a hacky way, by checking if next element is a number, then considering the current as artist name, but it'd be easier as CSV

Comment: Yes I understood. looks like there is no easy way to do it for such file structure. By the way it will be list consists of dictionaries. I forgot mention it.

Comment: I figured out that in the original file the attributes are splitted with tab. so there is no single space between attributes. How can I do that now?

Comment: The data you are showing appears inconsistent. In some of the lines the title and artist appear to be separated by a tab and in others a space. Please [edit] your question to include the *exact* data you are wanting to process.

Comment: Please clarify your question, and provide a [mcve]. See [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, unless there is a good reason not to do so variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are delimitted by a tab, you can fetch them like this:

```py
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    songs = []
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        songs.append(Song(
            fields[0],
            fields[1],
            fields[2],
            fields[3]
        ))
```

Alternatively, if you have the songs as a list of dictionaries, you can get a list of song objects with the following code:

```py
songObjects = []
for song in songList:
    songObjects.append(Song(
        song["title"],
        song["artist"],
        song["duration"],
        song["type"]
    ))
```

This code could go within your **init** function for Playlist if you want to pass it songList during creation.

Comment: Yes thanks. but the thing is I got stuck at fetching data properly according to attributes.

Comment: hey if you don't mind can you add your previous code. thanks

Comment: I've added back the code from my original response. If it has helped, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment but imo there is no way python could differentiate between the title and the artist if those are only seperated by one space.

```
Te Robare Nicky Jam
```

I don't know the artist here it could be

```
title: Te Robare, artist: Nicky Jam
```

or

```
title: Te Robare Nicky, artist: Jam
```

A solution could be comparing the splits with a list of artists but this creates other problems.

Comment: I figured out that in the original file the attributes are splitted with tab. so there is no single space between attributes. How can I do that now?

Comment: I would suggest a split("\t")